# NLTK context free grammar - take value of RHS to LHS with some kind of wildcard?

Tags: python, nltk

Consider I want to query a movie database where the NL query is "Show me all films starring <insert actor name here>".

I don't want to have to create a production for every possible actor.  I can build the grammar to handle "Show me all films starring ", but how could I possible handle the "wild card" problem of actor being any possible value, so I could for example take any value from the right hand side and propagate it to the left then upwards?

As a simpler example with more limited scope, with regard to rating of movies, I got as far as the NNP (to handle rating values of PG, R etc), but say I don't want to hardcode the values of rating,  This will be especially critical when wanting to handle a specific movie or actor name.

```
% start S
S[SEM=(?vp + ?np)] -> VP[SEM=?vp] NP[SEM=?np]
VP[SEM=(?vb)] -> VB[SEM=?vb]
NP[SEM=(?nns + ?vbn + ?nnp)] -> NNS[SEM=?nns] VBN[SEM=?vbn] NNP[SEM=?nnp]
VB[SEM='SELECT'] -> 'show' | 'display' | 'list'
NNS[SEM='title, description, category, rating FROM film_list'] -> 'films'
VBN[SEM='WHERE rating'] -> 'rated'
NNP ->
```

Comment: I think I have just seen a possible solution to this as provided in response to another question that alvas replied to, by way of using a "tag" to replace explicit values, handling the tag in the grammer ad then replacing the tag with the explicit value again after parsing. Will give this a go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348485/how-to-match-integers-in-nltk-cfg

Comment: Yes, creating a LHS non-terminal tag for the RHS terminal would be a "simple" solution to using placeholders

Comment: Do you still need further help on the question or would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348485/how-to-match-integers-in-nltk-cfg be sufficient?